# Inter container communication in Kubernetes multi container Pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have a pod with 3 containers A, B, and C. I would like to access service in Container A and B from C. Neither `localhost:<port>` is working nor the `127.0.0.1`.

my yaml

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: web3
  labels:
    name: web
    app: demo
spec:
  containers:
    - name: client
      image: ubuntu
      command: ['cat']
      tty: true
    - name: apache1
      image: nimmis/apache-php5
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
          name: apacheport1
          protocol: TCP
    - name: apache2
      image: nimmis/apache-php5
      command: ['cat']
      tty: true
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8088
          name: apacheport2
          protocol: TCP
```

what I am doing

```
kubectl apply -f example.yaml
kubectl exec -it web3 -c client bash
```

and then try to reach other 2 services

```
root@web3:/# curl http://localhost:8080
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused
root@web3:/# curl http://localhost:8088
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8088: Connection refused
root@web3:/# curl http://localhost:80

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <!--
    Modified from the Debian original for Ubuntu
```

Questions
 How to make the first 2 curl work. (I do not want to use the service since my use case is only for testing purpose)
 Why there is an open port 80 when I haven't exposed the port.

Comment: what's the exposed port inside the nimmis/apache-php5 image?

Comment: 80 and 443 ports are open in Apache container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that with `nimmis/apache-php5` Apache is listening on port 80.
So, it's port 80 which is exposed.
Through `containerPort: <P>` you are not saying to expose container's port 80 to `<P>`, but rather exposing port `<P>` itself. Also, as written in the docs, `Not specifying a port here DOES NOT prevent that port from being exposed.`.

I did not find a way to map an internal container port to a different port in the pod. However, you may map the internal container port to a host port through field `hostPort`.

```
apiVersion: "v1"
kind: Pod
metadata:
name: web3
labels:
name: web
app: demo
spec:
containers:
- name: client
  image: ubuntu
  command: ['cat']
  tty: true
- name: apache1
  image: nimmis/apache-php5
  ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      name: apacheport1
      hostPort: 8002
      protocol: TCP
- name: apache2
  image: nimmis/apache-php5
  command: ['cat']
  tty: true
  ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      hostPort: 8001
      name: apacheport2
      protocol: TCP
```

Then you get the IP of the node, e.g., on Minikube

```
$ minikube ip  # e.g., 192.168.97.100
```

and check that, from `client`, you can access the Apache services:

```
$ kubectl exec -it web3 -c client bash
# apt-get update && apt-get install curl
# curl 192.168.99.100:8002
```

Comment: There is no way to replicate -p hostPort:containerPort behavior of docker in a Pod ?

Comment: An option would be to use `hostPort` to expose the `containerPort: 80` to a port of the host. Then, you would `curl` at `hostIP:hostPort`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your time. I tried that option but couldn’t create a pod when I had host port mapping enabled. Do you have a minimal working example handy somewhere? I also read somewhere that the hostPort actually refers to the actual kubernetes node.

Comment: Yes, it maps a port on the cluster node running the pod.
I've extended the answer with an example.
I just would like to remark that exposing stuff is done through services.

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies my question and I have better understanding now towards the solution.